# ScanDir() access Denied

Tags: php, scandir

I'm using Scandir to pull a list of pdfs from a directory and create links for them to the user. I'm fairly sure its a permission issue as the errors are:

> [11-Feb-2015 08:31:29 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  scandir(\IIS-1\blackwood\,\IIS-1\blackwood): Access is denied. (code: 5) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SIdetail.php on line 20
>
> [11-Feb-2015 08:31:29 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  scandir(\IIS-1\blackwood): failed to open dir: No error in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SIdetail.php on line 20
>
> [11-Feb-2015 08:31:29 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  scandir(): (errno 0): No error in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SIdetail.php on line 20

I've searched thru this and several other forums to try and find the correct permission setup, but it eludes me. We're running IIS 8.5 with php 5.5. I've made sure the IIS-User has permission on the necessary folders, as well as the root folder for the website as well. System, Network Service, Administrators all also have full permission on the folders per other forums threads, but still to no avail.  Any idea??

Comment: To peoples passing by, when programming locally, this error can appear due to a change in the path while HOT-plugging an external HDD. It may not be a permission error, but a PATH error, even if it raises a permission error. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the user under which IIS process is running and allow that user to access the files. Amongst the local users you should find IIS something as a user.

Comment: The IIS worker Process (w3wp.exe) is running under the DefaultAppPool user. I've added that user to security tab and just to be sure, the shared users following the guide laid out [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities). Again, just to be sure I restarted the IIS and webpage. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you set Windows integrated security and have IIS impersonating the users? In which case you would have to adjust the folder access accordingly.

Comment: If at loss, switch auditing ON for access failure and examine Windows logs.

Comment: IIS 8.5 sets authentication as a default to IIS_User, not the application pool user. So for anyone following along... in IIS 8.5, goto Authentication, edit the Anonymous Authentication and select 'Application Pool Identiy' Restart IIS and All is good.  Thank-you Tarik. (if I was able I've vote this answer up.)